# How to use Bash Regex Lookbehind across whitespace in Terraform file?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep, hcl

I'm writing a bash script to parse a bunch (a dozen or more) massive Terraform files that contain a large number of google_bigquery_dataset resources and their associated IAM access blocks. The script should take each dataset resource and copy it to another file, named for the dataset itself.

All of this is fine, except extracting the name of the dataset from the resource's "dataset_id" field. This would be easy enough, if not for the fact that some of these dataset resources have authorized view blocks that also contain "dataset_id" values.

Here is an example of such a resource:

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "project-bigquery-dataset-RESOURCE_NAME" {
  access {
    role          = "WRITER"
    special_group = "projectWriters"
  }

  access {
    role          = "READER"
    special_group = "projectReaders"
  }

  access {
    role          = "WRITER"
    user_by_email = "user1@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }

  access {
    role          = "OWNER"
    special_group = "projectOwners"
  }

  access {
    view {
      dataset_id = "DO_NOT_WANT"
      project_id = "project"
      table_id   = "table1"
    }
  }

  access {
    view {
      dataset_id = "DO_NOT_WANT"
      project_id = "project"
      table_id   = "table2"
    }
  }

  access {
    view {
      dataset_id = "DO_NOT_WANT"
      project_id = "project"
      table_id   = "table3"
    }
  }

  dataset_id                      = "THIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT"
  default_partition_expiration_ms = "0"
  delete_contents_on_destroy      = "false"

  labels = {
    application-name = "app-name"
  }

  location = "US"
  project  = "project"
}
```

Before I realized that the authorized view blocks also had a `dataset_id` field, I was using this to try to grab the value I wanted, assuming `startIndex` and `endIndex` are just the start and end line numbers representing a complete dataset resource block as above:

```
fileName=$( sed -n ${startIndex},${endIndex}p $bigFile | grep "dataset_id" | cut -d\" -f2)
```

Which works only when there are not Authorized View blocks contained other `dataset_id` values.

I then tried to use a Negative Lookbehind:

```
fileName=$( sed -n ${startIndex},${endIndex}p $bigFile | grep '(?<!view {]n)dataset_id' | cut -f1 -d\"
```

That doesn't work. I'm not sure if it's because of the newline or because of the whitespace between the end of `view {` and the start of `dataset_id = "DO_NOT_WANT"`.

I've tried variations on it, such as `(?<!view\s{\s)\s*dataset_id` without success.

Is there any way to capture only the `dataset_id` that isn't in a view block?

A couple notes:

1. I can guarantee that `view {` will always precede the `dataset_id` in a block, without a line break.
2. I cannot guarantee the order. It's possible the `dataset_id` I'm trying to capture could be present before the `view` blocks, after them, or even somewhere between them.
3. Desired output for the above example would simply be `THIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT`
   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume that `awk` is a better tool for your requirement.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `grep` implements BRE, and optionally ERE. Standard `grep` has no lookahead or lookbehind capabilities at all -- that's PCRE syntax. Have you thought about using a perl oneliner? (perl is, after all, where PCRE comes from).

Comment: (also, grep is _not_ "bash regex" support; the regex support built into bash uses `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` syntax - though that's ERE syntax, so it too doesn't support lookbehind. `grep` is a completely independent tool provided by your operating system vendor, not part of bash).

Comment: This might help: `grep '^  dataset_id' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```bash
awk -v RS= -v FS="\n" '
/^[[:space:]]+dataset_id[[:space:]]+/{
  split($1,arr,"\"")
  print arr[2]
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation for complete code would be:

- Setting `RS`(Record separator) as paragraph mode in `awk` program.
- Then setting `FS`(Field separator) as new line.
- Then in main block checking condition if line starts from 1 or more spaces followed by `dataset_id` followed by again 1 or more spaces, if this condition is TRUE then:
- Using `split` function of `awk` to split $1(first field) into an array named `arr` with delimiter of `"`. This basically creates an array named `arr` with index of 1 2 3 4 and so on depending upon how many elements it splits based on delimiter.
- Then printing array `arr`'s 2nd element which is required output by OP.

Answer (score 1):

If your `grep` supports `-P` (PCRE) option, would you please try the following. It is tested with your shown sample.

```
grep -Poz '(?:^|\n)(?:(?!view).)*\n\s*dataset_id\s*=\s*"\K[^"]+' input_file
```

Output:

```
THIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT
```

**Assumption**

- If `view {` preceds the `dataset_id`, the two words span consecutive
  two lines.

**Explanations**

- As we need to examine the pattern match across lines, `-z` option is put
  to `grep` to treat the input as sequences of lines.
- The regex `(?:^|\n)(?:(?!view).)*\n\s*dataset_id\s*=\s*"\K[^"]+`
  matches (at least) two lines which do not contain the word `view`
  in the previous line before the line containing `dataset_id`.
- `(?:^|\n)` anchors the start of the line, as the multiline option
  `(?m)` does not work due to the `-z` option.
- As the `lookbehind` assertion does not allow variable length match, we need
  to use `(?:(?!view).)*` as an alternative for `(?<!view.*)`.
- The following `\n\s*dataset_id` makes sure at least one newline
  exists between `view` and `dataset_id`. Otherwise the regex matches a
  single line which just contains `dataset_id` causing over-detection.
- `\K` discards the previous matched substring to exclude it in the output.

Answer (score 0):

not guaranteed to work with your hcl, but could try converting to json first

```bash
$ cat foo.tf | 
yj -c | 
jq  -r '.resource[].google_bigquery_dataset[][][].dataset_id'
THIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT
THIS_IS_WHAT_I_WANT
```